# Source on the proof that codimension 2 is sufficient for knottings?

Tags: knot-theory, at.algebraic-topology

Hi all.

I'm not even sure that this is a theorem, but a while ago I heard a topologist friend of mine (whom I haven't been able to reach) saying that given a continuous embedding $f:M^{n}\to N^{r}$ ($M$ and $N$ being topological manifolds), a sufficient condition for $f(M)$ to be (possibly) knotted in $N$ is that $r=2n$. Does anyone know if this is even true? Also, if it is true then the following question seems natural: will the embedding still be knotted if $r>2n$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you make your question more precise, like what do you want *knotted* to mean for topological embeddings? 

Comment: ``Codimension 2'' means $r=n+2$.

Comment: The logical meaning of "a sufficient condition for STATEMENT to be possibly true" is rather unclear.

Comment: I guess the only example I have in mind is where $M$ is a torus. By knotted I mean that the image of the torus in $N$ won't be isotopic to a 'standard' embedded torus by a transformation of the ambient space, much like in the case of $n=1$ and $r=3$. 

Comment: @Lee: I concur and apologize. What I meant is the following: given the embedding $f$, if $r<2n$ then the embedded manifold will be isotopic to a 'standardly embedded' one (once again, I guess this only makes sense for $M=T^n$ and $N=S^r$) by a transformation of the ambient space; if $r=2n$ then it won't be. I found this: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604045 and I'm reading it right now; I'll let you know if there's something interesting there. Thanks.

Comment: Your last question is still unclear.  You refer to "the embedding" as if it came from somewhere else.  Do you mean to say "can an embedding be knotted if..." ? 

Comment: @Ryan: yes, I ask the question for any possible embedding. So I rephrase thus:
Let $g,f:M^n\to N^r$ be embeddings. Is it true that if $r<2n$ then $f$ and $g$ will always be isotopic whereas if $r\geq 2n$ they needn't be?

Comment: The answer to your latter question is no.  For example $n=0, r=1$.  Let $M$ be a space consisting of $k$ points, with the discrete topology, and $N=S^1$.  There are $(k-1)!$ isotopy classes of embeddings $M \to N$. 

Comment: I think you are trying to ask "For which range of dimensions does homotopy of two maps always imply isotopy?" Another form could be: Given such and such dimensions, every embedding $f$ of one manifold to another could be homotoped to another embedding $g$, so that $f$ is not isotopic to $g$.  

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52692/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is badly posed. If you have a not simply connected manifold (of any dimension $> 3$) then two connected closed curves are isotopic iff they are homotopic, hence you have as many isotopy classes of curves as the conjugacy classes in the fundamental group.
Also, following your comment, in codimension two (which means $r = n + 2$) there are a lot of "knotted" submanifolds: classical knots in $S^3$, 2-knots in $S^4$ and in general knotted spheres of dimension $r-2$ in $S^r$. In any manifold there are knotted codimension two submanifolds (i.e. pairs of non-isotopic embeddings of the same manifold in the ambient space). And this satisfies $r < 2 (r - 2)$ if $r > 4$.